# Related questions overflow

Tags: bug, design

The text can flow out of the bottom of the related sidebar when the titles are too long.

[image: Related sidebar]

Comment: Yeah, this happens to me, too. It’s a simple programming error. Have you checked whether it happens on other SE sites as well?

Comment: I've not noticed it on other SE sites, but I wouldn't guarantee it never happens there.

Comment: It would seem that many of the other SE sites don't use decorative boxes as part of their side bar for related sites.